# is it possible to get a property by its value in c#

Tags: c#, hibernate, reflection

I have this code where I compare the values of oldState object by the currentState in fluent inhibernate, what I want is to log the property that has been changed and its value,here I get the new and the old values but I waant also to get the property name.

if I reflect `@event.Entity` I can get all the properties and their values so is there any way to get the property name by its value.

```
public void OnPostUpdate(NHibernate.Event.PostUpdateEvent @event)
{
    var entityToAudit = @event.Entity as IAuditable;
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AuditLog.txt");
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < @event.OldState.Length; i++)
        {
            if (@event.OldState[i] != null)
            {
                if (!@event.OldState[i].Equals(@event.State[i]))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("the value has ben changed from " + @event.OldState[i] + " to " + @event.State[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (@event.State[i] != null)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("the value has ben changed from being empty to " + @event.State[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `System.Reflection` for that. `PostUpdateEvent` already contains all the property names in the order you need :

```
var propertyName = e.Persister.PropertyNames[i];
```